# How to select photos and open gallery from fragment?

Tags: android-studio

How to display image from gallery using Profile Fragment in android studio?

I use imageview (ivGallery) to go to gallery and the selected picture will appear in (ivProfilePicture).

Answer (score 2):

- First you call intent

  ```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
  android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
  ```
- Then you will get image data on OnActivityResult

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
      Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
      String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
      Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
      String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
      cursor.close();
      ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
      imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }      
  }
  ```